# pg_restore: Could not read input file - Mac OS vs Windows

Tags: macos, postgresql, dump, database-restore, pg-restore

On my Mac OS X 10.11.3 using pgAdmin3 or pg_restore via command line i'm getting an error trying to restore a production dump (generated by ubuntu linux server) shown bellow:

> pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of
>   file

Here's the command used to restore:

```
./pg_restore --host 52.11.108.XXX --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "bdtenaXXXXXX" --role "postgres" --verbose "/Users/viniciussouza/Desktop/homologacao"
```

The whole schema was created susccefully but when starts data creation, error occurs.

Tried on a local postgres 9.3 (installed on my mac os) and same error. When i tried to do the restore using pgAdmin3 on a Windows 7 Machine, no errors! Can anybody help me?